# how to get all tweets on hashtag using Tweetsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, tweets, tweetsharp

How can I get all tweets on behalf of specific hashtag/keyword and display it on View page? The only solution found returns a null exception.

```
public ActionResult TweetView(string txtTwitterName)
{
    //TwitterService("consumer key", "consumer secret");
    var service = new TwitterService("", "");

    //AuthenticateWith("Access Token", "AccessTokenSecret");
    service.AuthenticateWith("", "");

    TwitterSearchResult tweets = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = txtTwitterName, SinceId=29999 });
    IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status = tweets.Statuses;
    ViewBag.Tweets = tweets;

    return View();
}
```

View :

```
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = ViewBag.Tweets as IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>;
foreach (var tweet in tweets)
{
    <div class="tweet">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="@tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl" alt="@tweet.User.ScreenName" title="@tweet.User.ScreenName" />
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <span>@tweet.User.Name, @tweet.User.Description - @tweet.User.Location </span>
            <br />
            <a href="https://twitter.com/statuses/@tweet.Id" class="text">
                @tweet.Text
            </a>
            <div class="action">
                @tweet.CreatedDate.AddHours(3).ToString("d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">

        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the null value, in your view :

```
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> status = ViewBag.Tweets as IEnumerable<TwitterStatus>;
if(status != null )
{
    foreach (var tweet in status)
    {
        <div class="tweet">
            <div class="picture">
                <img src="@tweet.User.ProfileImageUrl" alt="@tweet.User.ScreenName"     
                 title="@tweet.User.ScreenName" />
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <span>@tweet.User.Name, @tweet.User.Description - @tweet.User.Location </span>
                <br />
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/statuses/@tweet.Id" class="text">
                @tweet.Text
                </a>
                <div class="action">
                    @tweet.CreatedDate.AddHours(3).ToString("d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="clear">

            </div>

        </div>
   }
}
```

and for your Controller, modify the last code by :

```
ViewBag.Tweets = status;
```

I hope this post will help, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem. Here is my vague solution. The function will return whenever your required number of tweets are returned. I hope it helps you.

```
        string maxid = "1000000000000"; // dummy value
        int tweetcount = 0;


        if (maxid != null)
        {
            var tweets_search = twitterService.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = keyword, Count = Convert.ToInt32(count) });
            List<TwitterStatus> resultList = new List<TwitterStatus>(tweets_search.Statuses);
            maxid = resultList.Last().IdStr;
            foreach (var tweet in tweets_search.Statuses)
            {
                try
                {
                    ResultSearch.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>(tweet.Id.ToString(), tweet.Text));
                    tweetcount++;
                }
                catch { }
            }

            while (maxid != null && tweetcount < Convert.ToInt32(count))
            {
                maxid = resultList.Last().IdStr;
                tweets_search = twitterService.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = keyword, Count = Convert.ToInt32(count), MaxId = Convert.ToInt64(maxid) });
                resultList = new List<TwitterStatus>(tweets_search.Statuses);
                foreach (var tweet in tweets_search.Statuses)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ResultSearch.Add(new KeyValuePair<String, String>(tweet.Id.ToString(), tweet.Text));
                        tweetcount++;
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }

        }
```